# How to group dataframe rows into one value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas data frame `df` like that :

```
a m b 
A x 1
A z 2
B x 5
B z 5
C x 4
C z 6
```

And I would like to group by the values of a column and have something like:

```
a m b 
A x 1
  z 2
B x 5
  z 5
C x 4
  z 6
```

Tried to use groupby but I think I tried in the wrong way

Comment: `groupby` returns a generator. Create a loop like `for key, value in df.groupby("a")`. You will have for each iteration key equals to "A", then "B", then "C". And, for values, a dataframe corresponding to that key. Usually `groupby` is used for aggregation purpose. Example: `df[["a", "b"]].groupby("a").sum()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to group here because there is no aggregation, just use `MultiIndex`:

```
out = df.set_index(['a', 'm'])
print(out)

# Output
     b
a m   
A x  1
  z  2
B x  5
  z  5
C x  4
  z  6
```